# Foundation Content Databases (2010)

Tags: 2010, content-database

How many content databases can be created with SharePoint Foundation 2010?  I am having a hard time finding the answer.  I think only one can be created but, I am not sure.

EDIT:

I did not think so.  Thank!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content Database Limit is same across Foundation to Standard to Enterprise versions.

In SharePoint 2010, Content Database Limit is 300 Content DB per web Application with 200GB size for each Content Database.

Check [this blog for more info.](http://shadiesm.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-server-2010-capacity.html)

This limit is changed in 2013 [check here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ContentDB)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely 1 is not the correct answer.

There is no documents available for SharePoint Foundation. But in case of SharePoint Server 2010 its 300 content databases per web application.

http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/10/03/sharepoint-2010-boundaries-thresholds-and-supported-limits/